# Why struct node* is written inside a struct node?

Tags: c++, data-structures, struct, nodes

I've seen many a times node classes in C++ being defined as:

```
struct node
{
    whatever data;
    struct node* pointerToAnyLinkedNode;
}
```

Now the question is why in line no. 4, 'struct' is written before node*? Does it have a special purpose? Because it does not pose any problem if I do not write it. I'm sorry if this question has a duplicate. I could not find one BTW.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the context and semantics? It's a usual pattern used for linked list implementation. Using `struct` is optional for c++.

Comment: Are you sure it was C++ and not C code? Those two are different languages (though they have some similarities)

Comment: Why don't we simply write "node* pointerToLinkedNode" ? In every sample code, I see "struct node* pointerToLinkedNode" whether it is for a queue or tree or whatever data structure.

Comment: @AbdulMateen the `struct` prefix is *required* in C, but is *optional* in C++. You are likely looking at C examples, or C++ examples that are intended to be compatible with C.

Comment: @RemyLebeau right. I guess most of the online tutorials are intentionally made backward compatible with C

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because this idiom originated in C (where struct types *have* to be named with `struct` at the start) and a disturbingly large proportion of the C++ community copy/pastes their code from online tutorials, rather than actually thinking about what they're doing.

(This is also why you'll see `struct tm` everywhere in C++ code, for no good reason.)

In C++, the `struct` keyword is redundant here.

To be fair, if you're writing a header and aiming for compatibility with C programs, that's a good reason to leave it in.

Comment: I'm actually implementing a tree in C++ so i guess it would be better if i do not use struct here as u said. Thank you for this elaborate explanation.

Comment: @AbdulMateen: Might want to check your C++ book. `struct` and `class` are almost the same, the sole difference being that the _default_ access of a `struct` is `public:`.

Comment: @AbdulMateen: The keyword `struct` defines a _class_ already, if that's what you mean. What MSalters said is almost true.